# Determine whether the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x) \sin(x^2) dx$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Do I have to integrate the expression by parts and then evaluate the limit to find if the following (improper) integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x) \sin(x^2) dx
$$
converges?

Please help me out.

Comment: No. Check for tests for convergence of integrals.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Actually, the answer to the question is (given as a hint) "It is $convergent$"....

Comment: have spend at least one of your own thoughts on this question?

Comment: @Nirbhay I think the "No" has refered to integrating by parts.

Comment: Your integrand can be written as $1/2(\cos(x^2-x) - \cos(x^2+x)$. It might be easier to show that each of the terms converges individually. E.g. for the second term, you could try the substitution $y=x^2+x$.

Comment: @Fabian That sounds promising... I'll try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have filled in all the details,
and here they are.

It turns out that
the integral does converge.

My method also shows that
the integrals
$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x^2\pm x)dx$
converge.

Use $\sin a \sin b = (\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b))/2$
to show that this depends on
$\int_0^{\infty} \cos(x^2\pm x)dx$.

I will now show that these converge
by looking at the intervals
where $x^2 = 2n \pi$.
In these intervals, 
$x$ is essentially constant,
so it is like the integral of cos,
which is zero.

Let
$x_n^2 = 2\pi n$,
so
$x_n = \sqrt{2\pi n}$.

Let
$I_n
=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} \cos(x^2+cx) dx
$,
where
$|c| \le 1$.

I will show that
$|I_n|
\lt \dfrac{1}{2\pi n^2}
$,
so 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x^2+cx)dx
$
converges.

Let
$y = x^2$,
so
$dy = 2x\ dx$
or
$dx = dy/(2x)
=dy/(2\sqrt{y}
$.
Let
$y_n
=\sqrt{x_n}
=2\pi n
$.

Then
$I_n
=\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \dfrac{\cos(y+c\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}dy
$.

Let's see how
the parts of $I_n$ vary.

$y_{n+1}
=y_n+2\pi
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{y_{n+1}}
&=\sqrt{y_n+2\pi}\\
&=\sqrt{y_n}\sqrt{1+2\pi/y_n}\\
&<\sqrt{y_n}(1+\pi/y_n)\\
&=\sqrt{y_n}+\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{y_n}}\\
\text{and}\\
\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_{n+1}}}
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_n}}(1+2\pi/y_n)^{-1/2}\\
&<\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_n}}(1-\dfrac{\pi}{y_n})\\
\text{and}\\
\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_{n+1}}}
&\gt\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_n}}(1-2\pi/y_n)\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_n}}-\dfrac{2\pi}{y_n^{3/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\dfrac1{2\sqrt{y_n}}\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \cos(y+c\sqrt{y})dy
\gt I_n
\gt \dfrac1{2\sqrt{y_{n+1}}}\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \cos(y+c\sqrt{y})dy
$.

Let
$J_n
=\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \cos(y+c\sqrt{y})dy
$.

Since
$|\cos'(y)| \le 1$,
$|\cos(y+c\sqrt{y})-\cos(y)|
\le |c\sqrt{y}|
$.
Since
$\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \cos(y)dy
= 0
$
and
$|c| \le 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
|J_n|
&\le\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} |c\sqrt{y}|dy\\
&=|c|\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \sqrt{y}dy\\
&=|c|\dfrac{y^{-1/2}}{-1/2}\big|_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}}\\
&=2|c|(y_n^{-1/2}-y_{n+1}^{-1/2})\\
&\lt 2(y_n^{-1/2}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{y_n}}+\dfrac{2\pi}{y_n^{3/2}})\\
&= \dfrac{4\pi}{y_n^{3/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
(finally!)

$\begin{array}\\
|I_n|
&\lt \dfrac1{2\sqrt{y_n}} J_n\\
&\lt \dfrac1{2\sqrt{y_n}} \dfrac{4\pi}{y_n^{3/2}}\\
&=  \dfrac{2\pi}{y_n^2}\\
&=  \dfrac{2\pi}{(2\pi n)^2}\\
&=  \dfrac{1}{2\pi n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

so the sum of the
$I_n$
converges.